# Three arrays in one foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working on a small "user list" system, and i need to foreach three arrays.
Here is what i "want to do":

```
<?php
$users = array("user1", "user2");
$descriptions = array("user1 description", "user2 description");
$socials = array("skype: user1", "skype: user2");
foreach ($users as $user && $description as $description && $socials as $social) {
echo "<tr><td style=\"width:60px\"><img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"{$user}'s profile picture\" src=\"blog/users/{$user}/avatar.png\"><br/>{$user}</td><td style=\"width:70%\">{$descriptions}</td><td style=\"text-align:left\">{$social}</td></tr>}";}
?>
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: If the arrays always have the same number of objects, couldn't you use a regular old for(;;) loop?

Comment: If you can Make a Multidimension array I suggest that `$user = array(
 "user1"=>array(
  "name"=>"user1"
  ,"description"=>"user1 description"
  ,"socials"=>"skype: user1"
 )
)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a null first parameter you build a multidimensional array from the three and then walk it with foreach

```
$combined = array_map(null, $users, $descriptions, $socials);
foreach ($combined as $user) {
    $username = $user[0];
    $description = $user[1];
    $social = $user[2];
    echo "<tr><td style=\"width:60px\"><img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"{$username}'s profile picture\" src=\"blog/users/{$username}/avatar.png\"><br/>{$username}</td><td style=\"width:70%\">{$description}</td><td style=\"text-align:left\">{$social}</td></tr>}";
}
```

Comment: This is the way I would be doing it. Allows you more freedom outside of a loop.

Comment: Essentially, you are suggesting that the data structure for the intended usage is not optimal - I would agree on that. The usage of `array_map` is clever, but it only tries to repair what might have been done wrong before the code that is shown in the question. I'd rather try to repair that code instead of repairing the data structure here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = array("user1", "user2"); 
$descriptions = array("user1 description", "user2 description"); 
$socials = array("skype: user1", "skype: user2"); $i = 0; 
foreach ($users as $user)
{ 
  $html .= "{$user}{$descriptions[$i]}{$socials[$i]}"; 
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: You DO get the current index of `$users` as the key in `foreach`, there is no need for `$i` to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` in the `foreach` to be able to call another array (assuming that they match up):

```
<?php
$users = array("user1", "user2");
$descriptions = array("user1 description", "user2 description");
$socials = array("skype: user1", "skype: user2");
foreach ($users as $key=>$user) {
echo "<tr><td style=\"width:60px\"><img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"{$user}'s profile picture\" src=\"blog/users/{$user}/avatar.png\"><br/>{$user}</td><td style=\"width:70%\">{$descriptions[$key]}</td><td style=\"text-align:left\">{$social[$key]}</td></tr>}";}
```

Addtionally, it is not recommended to have so many lines of code in one `echo`. I prefer the `heredoc` approach that "breaks" everything apart, so that you can visually read (and make changes):

```
foreach ($users as $key=>$user) {
    echo <<<EOD

    <tr>
        <td style="width:60px"><img width="50" height="50" alt="{$user}'s profile picture" src="blog/users/{$user}/avatar.png"><br>{$user}</td>
        <td style="width:70%">{$descriptions[$key]}</td>
        <td style="text-align:left">{$social[$key]}</td>
    </tr>
EOD;
}
```

Comment: Or you can just break it up with `foreach ($blah as $blahblah) { ?>stuff<?php }`

Comment: which is what I did. i don't understand your comment

Comment: Kinda. `<?php foreach($something as $else) { ?>Put some stuff here, outside of an echo/heredoc/nowdoc <?php } ?>` Note the opening and closing tags before/after the looped text. Just an alternative way to say what you did.

Comment: I prefer the way I mentioned due to my IDE's syntax highlighting not picking up inside heredoc/nowdocs. But its just easier to read in my opinion regardless

Comment: why stop the php processing, when there are no conditions to be met? if it's just straight echoing content into the source code then you shouldn't close the process, then open it again just to continue in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: More acurately: why stop the php processing for HTML output? even if it is only echoing content, to stop the process just to print content, then open the PHP processor again, JUST to re-run the `foreach` loop doesn't make since to me.

Comment: I *think* there is no starting and stopping involved. PHP will parse the source, and any occurrence of content outside PHP tags as well as any echo or print will be handled identically.

Answer (score 0):

Run a for loop, the go thru all 3 array at once.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++)
{
    echo $users[$i].'<br />'; //get location $i of array $users
    echo $descriptions[$i].'<br />'; //get location $i of array $descriptions
    echo $socials[$i].'<br />'; //get location $i of array $socials
}
```